# Video Streaming with Jackrabbit

Tags: apache, content-management-system, jackrabbit

Which Audio/Video  Streaming server(industry standard) can be integrate with Apache JackRabbit content Repository?

Answer (score 0):

The JCR spec and Jackrabbit itself don't provide anything specific regarding media streaming.

Binary data is accessed via the [Binary](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Binary.html) interface, you could implement streaming based on the InputStream that this provides.